# How is the TLS 1.2 sequence number generated?

Tags: tls

In the other ciphers supported by TLS 1.2, namely stream cipher and CBC block cipher mode, the sequence number is implicitly in the MAC (RFC5246, 6.2.3.1):

```
MAC = HMAC(MAC_write_key, seq_num +
                      TLSCompressed.type +
                      TLSCompressed.version +
                      TLSCompressed.length +
                      TLSCompressed.fragment);
```

How many bytes is `seq_num`? How is the sequence number generated? There seems to be no explicit information about this in the RFC document.

Comment: Hi Zeta. I've changed the question quite a bit to make it more readable. Please verify that I didn't break it. If the `seq_num` is mentioned in the section then it is *explicit*, not *implicit*.

Comment: FWIW a mnemonic is that RHUL's 'Lucky 13' attack works because the pseudoheader is 13 bytes = **8** +1+2+2 and 13 bytes plus 9 bytes MD-padding is only slightly more than 20 bytes HMAC-SHA1. Okay, not a very simple mnemonic and it's probably easier to just read the RFC :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many bytes is `seq_num`?

To quote the RFC (section 6.1; item 'sequence number')

```
 Sequence numbers are of type uint64
```

That is, they are 8 bytes long

> How is the sequence number generated?

From the same section:

```
 A sequence number is incremented after each
 record: specifically, the first record transmitted under a
 particular connection state MUST use sequence number 0.
```

That is, the sequence number for the first record is 0, the sequence number for the second record is 1, the sequence number for the hundredth record is 99.

Comment: Thanks.. Is it like server 0,1,2,3... client 0,1,2,3. Or server 0 client 1 server 2 client 3..

Comment: And when resumption, does it restart from 0?

Comment: @Zeta: TLS is not a request-response protocol; instead, either side can send records independently (just like TCP).  Hence, the sequence numbers for the client-to-server direction, and the sequence numbers for the server-to-client direction are independent.

Comment: @Zeta: session resumption generates fresh cryptographical keys, and so yes, the sequence numbers restart at 0